# Call a js file from a plugin directory

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am creating a WP plugin. In the plugin folder I have a js folder which contains a small js file named call.js. The plugin also have a functions.php file.

Now, I am getting issues (like js content being visible on the front end) which outing the js.

In the plugin functions.php I have the following

```
function basic_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/call.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'basic_script');
```

The plugin file also looks correct

```
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/call.js';
```

I added the following js in the js file

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
var newVal = $('#div2');
$('#div1').html( newVal );
});
})(jQuery)
```

I understand I am making error somewhere but unable to find this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks..I am creating my own wordpress plugin

Comment: i think problem in function.so , remove it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var newVal = $('#div2');
$('#div1').html( newVal );
});
```

remove function code

Comment: Thanks for your time. I can see the whole of js codes on the front end. Is there an issue with en-queuing this properly or something like this?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Actually it did not work. Still thanks. Let me find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You've enqueued the JS file correctly. An alert should help you verify that.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert ('success');
    });
})(jQuery)
```

What exactly is the desired behavior?

Also note that this line is not needed. `require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/call.js';`